# Enabling key event handling for gtk# (Mono)

Tags: mono, keyboard, gtk, keypress, gtk#

The following code does not trigger the `KeyPress` event when the user presses a key...

```
public class FooWidget : DrawingArea {

    public FooWidget () {
        this.AddEvents ((int)Gdk.EventMask.KeyPressMask);
    }

    [GLib.ConnectBefore]
    protected override bool OnKeyPressEvent (Gdk.EventKey evnt) {
        Console.WriteLine (evnt);
        return base.OnKeyPressEvent (evnt);
    }

}
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it myself:

You need to be able to focus on the `Widget`:

```
this.CanFocus = true;
this.Focus();
```